# Realm Insert New Schema in ReactNative

Tags: react-native, realm, realm-migration

```
const schema1 = [

    rolesSchema,
    userMutedInRoomSchema,
    uploadsSchema,
    usersForMentionSchema,
    contactsSchema,
];
const schema2 = [

    rolesSchema,
    userMutedInRoomSchema,
    uploadsSchema,
    usersForMentionSchema,
    contactsSchema,
    stickersPackagesSchema,
    stickersCollectionSchema
];
```

Above are the two schemas Schema1 is the one i am using already and it is working fine Schema2 is the new schema in which i have added new tables(schemas) at the end after contacts schema. I have followed the documenntation but i couldn't find anything that explains adding new tables in the old schema . Below is the code i am using to initialize new schema which crashes on run time

```
const path = database.replace(/(^\w+:|^)\/\//, '');
        return this.databases.activeDB = new Realm({
            path: `${ path }Value.realm`,
            schema:schema2,
            schemaVersion:1,
            migration: (oldRealm, newRealm) => {


            },
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are updating the schema of a production app. Then you need to write the migration logic and update the schemaVersion.

```
Realm.open({
  schema: [PersonSchema],
  schemaVersion: 1,
  migration: (oldRealm, newRealm) => {
    // only apply this change if upgrading to schemaVersion 1
    if (oldRealm.schemaVersion < 1) {
      const oldObjects = oldRealm.objects('Person');
      const newObjects = newRealm.objects('Person');

      // loop through all objects and set the name property in the new schema
      for (let i = 0; i < oldObjects.length; i++) {
        newObjects[i].name = oldObjects[i].firstName + ' ' + oldObjects[i].lastName;
      }
    }
  }
}).then(realm => {
  const fullName = realm.objects('Person')[0].name;
});
```

Refer: https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/#performing-a-migration

If you are currently developing the app, then you can just update the schemaVersion and add the `deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded` property to delete old stale data

Refer: https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/#opening-realms